# Document's total height function's return value changes on browser refresh (F5)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a function for calculating the document's height like this:

```
 function getFinalHeight() {
      var body = document.body,
              html = document.documentElement;

      return Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
              html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);    
  }
```

The function works fine when a new request to the document is made.

However, when I press F5 to refresh the page, another value which is smaller than the correct value is returned.

The code is at:
https://jsfiddle.net/myn0u9oc/1/

For example when a new request is made the return value of the getfinalheight function is correct i.e. 1740px however when I press F5 it returns a different value i.e. 1440px.

I wonder if this has anything to do with **browser caching** and stuff? I'm new to web design so please could somebody tell me what went wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: When do you run the code? Document height can be affected by many things, including images that load after initial parsing.

Comment: It is a very basic html without any images. The function works fine the page's content is confined in one window. However if the page has more content making it scrollable then the function does not work correctly on f5 any more. https://jsfiddle.net/myn0u9oc/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm late but for those with future trouble:
You probably have done something that takes longer to load which means the actual height changes when the entire document is loaded, making the beforehand returned value incorrect.

I had the same issue, if you wrap this function in:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    
});
```

then everything should work correctly.